# Duplicate interface definition for class 'CAMetalLayer' Xcode Error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

When I try to build my Unity3D app in Xcode (11.3) I got the errors bellow, how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Unity 2018.2.18f1

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Can you please help?

Comment: I got the same issue. I can't fix it.

Comment: @huync The only solution is to update Unity to the last version :)

Answer (score 0):

When you build your iOS version in Unity, select `Xcode v11.0`[image]